# QuickBlox JavaScript SDK - is there a simpler video chat sample?

Tags: javascript, quickblox

Trying to integrate the video chat into a website, and I'm finding difficulty with trying to integrate elements from the sample given in the SDK. I'm using Chrome and Firefox for testing and it is now telling me that WebRTC is not supported (which is impossible obviously)!
Is there a simpler example somewhere that shows a basic way to connect and allow just 2 people to do video chat?
I'm pulling my hair out over the javascript in general, as any minor incorrect change breaks the whole thing.

Comment: What exact issues do you have?
Can you create a GitHub issue here https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/issues and send a link here

Comment: It's more trying to understand what/how the sample does what it does with linking up and starting a video chat. Trying to integrate that into an existing project is proving difficult. Would be nice if there was some sort of Step by Step tutorial to show how to just link 2 people up for video chat. Tried viewing documentation, but the skeleton code shown is not helping me to work out what might be wrong or how to do it right. I'm sure I've probably mucked up some JS somewhere in trying to use the sample code, hence the "WebRTC not supported" error in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

are you using https? Could you give more information (logs) or use https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/issues/new .

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: With regards to any URLs using QuickBlox related servers, they are all using https